# Unable to use Components in WebExtensions: get "ReferenceError: Cu is not defined"

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a simple extension where I use `Cu.import` to import a [JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules). But, when I load the extension, I get this error:

```
Cu is not defined
```

The code I was trying to use was:

```js
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/MatchPattern.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/BrowserUtils.jsm");

var regExArray = [];
var myArray = ["facebook.com", "google.com"];

var myURL="http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd";

for (var x=0; x<myArray.length; x++)
{   
    console.log("loop: "+x);
    var match = new MatchPattern(/(http:\/\/)(.*\.)*(myArray[x])(\/.*)*(\/)*/);
    log("match result is: "+match.matches(myURL));     
}//end for loop
```

I know how to define `Cu` in the Firefox Add-on SDK using [`require`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority), but how can define it in WebExtesnions?

Comment: I have significantly edited your question to focus it on the single primary issue blocking the way that you were implementing your code. As written, your Question contained multiple questions, which were not closely related due to your actual error being separate from Match Patterns. While the question, as it is now, does address the actual error you were getting for your code, it does not address your other questions. Those would be best asked in a separate Question focused on Match Patterns instead of the error you were getting.I made the edit because I felt that having a general (continued)

Comment: question about this issue would be beneficial to Stack Overflow as a target which we could use to close as duplicate any other questions with a similar issue (about `Cu`/`Components` used in WebExtensions). However, it is *your* question, so feel free to revert my edit if you desire. If you want to get the original text of your question, it's available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/004db903-0511-4da4-afb2-af1da5b2ad0f/view-source), which can be used as a basis for a new questions specifically about Match Patterns in WebExtensions, without mixing in older technologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can *NOT* use `Components` in WebExtensions

For the older Firefox extension types, the `Components` Object provided access to low-level capabilities in Firefox. The common aliases are:

- `Cc = Components.classes`
- `Ci = Components.interfaces`
- `Cu = Components.util`
- `Cr = Components.results`
- `Cm = Components.manager`
- `components = Components`

In the Add-on SDK these were described in the [Chrome Authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority) documentation and were available by using

```
var {Cc, Ci, Cu, Cr, Cm, components} = require("chrome");
```

## `Components` does not exist in WebExtensions

Access to these low-level capabilities **does not exist in WebExtensions**. Remove it from your code and forget about it. Don't try to use anything connected to it, because you can't do so. Removing access to the low-level capabilities provided by `Components` is one of the specific reasons for moving to WebExtensions.

If you see it in a page on MDN, then that page is not about WebExtensions and should be ignored for WebExtensions development. You should see *at the top of every such page* a large warning stating that you should be using WebExtensions instead of the technology described on that page. The warning currently (2017-06-17) looks like:

[image: MDN old extension warning]

## If you need something that exists in older extensions, but not in WebExtensions, try a [WebExtensions Experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

You can extend the capabilities of WebExtensions by constructing a WebExtensions Experiment. The intent is to allow add-on developers to create new APIs for WebExtensions which are proposed for inclusion into Firefox. However, there is no guarantee that such proposals will actually be integrated into Firefox.

Comment: What is the right way to read profile preferences? Please, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202669/how-to-read-profile-preferences-from-firefox-add-on