# How to import service classes in Mozilla WebExtensions

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am migrating an addon from mozilla. (Migrating from ADDONS-SDK to WebExtensions technology, however I'm encountering problems when importing the main API classes.

When the plugin was made with ADDON-SDK, the import was done like this:

```
// Import the main SDK libs to use in the project
var data = require ("sdk / self").
var pageMod = require ("sdk / page-mod");
var utils = require ('sdk / window / utils');

const {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require ("chrome");
const Ac = console;

// Loading services
const OS = Cc ['@ mozilla.org/observer-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
const LOADER = Cc ['@ mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1'].getService(Ci.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
const IOS = Cc ["@ mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);

// import browser configuration files
Cu.import ("resource: //gre/modules/Services.jsm");

// Loading other project files
LOADER.loadSubScript ('chrome: //vigiamcviewer/content/HTTP.js');
```

However, in WebExtensions, I did not find anything like doing the imports.

I've browsed the API and found a good example of the SDK, but nothing like how to do the same with WebExtensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use Components in WebExtensions: get "ReferenceError: Cu is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608110/unable-to-use-components-in-webextensions-get-referenceerror-cu-is-not-define)

Comment: Yes, in fact, this is the answer. Thanks a lot!