# How to read profile preferences from Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm doing this (Firefox 66.0.5, MacOS):

```
var prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1']
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
var x = pref.getCharPref('extensions.foo.x');
```

I'm getting this:

```
JavaScript error: moz-extension://9390a488-d749-d140-91b6-fb1b2a86053f/foo.js,
line 1: TypeError: Components.classes is undefined
```

What is the right way to read the preferences of the profile?

I tried this:

```
var prefs = Components.classesByID['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1']
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
```

And got this:

```
JavaScript error: moz-extension://ebac8f96-717d-0c4b-b2d3-a7d6f3515843/auth.js,
line 1: TypeError: Components.classesByID is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebExtensions are *very* limited in their ability to make changes to user preferences. There are a few, currently 14, that you can affect through the [`browserSettings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserSettings) API. There are others which are *effectively* changed through other WebExtension APIs (e.g. [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy)), but nothing directly. Unfortunately, there's no direct way to read or set user preferences from a WebExtension. The capability to adjust user preferences directly was only available to the older styles of add-ons (all removed as of Firefox 57).

As to your use of `Components` and the specific errors which you are getting, please see my answer to [Unable to use Components in WebExtensions: get “ReferenceError: Cu is not defined”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44608767/3773011) for more detail. The use of `Components` is just not possible in a WebExtension.

The only way that I can think of that it might be possible to adjust preferences in a release version of Firefox is to use [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) to communicate to a native application which you also install. After Firefox exits/stops/is shutdown, the native application could read and change the configuration files in the profile directory for the Firefox profile being run. It could then restart Firefox.

In the Nightly and Developer Edition versions of Firefox, it should still be possible to use a [WebExtensions Experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which would permit you to make the preference changes you desire using the `Components` interface. However, that's not a viable solution if this is an extension you want to distribute publicly.

Comment: @yegor256 I'm not that familiar with Selenimum, so I'm not really a great fit for that question. Unfortunately, WebExtensions is *extremely* limited compared to what the old add-on types were capable of. It may not be possible to get that information.

Comment: Maybe you can think of _any_ other possible ways to send information from the command line, where `firefox` is started, to the add-on?